# Como verificar se um dado ja está na minha lista

Tags: c, estrutura-de-dados

Bom, estou tentando fazer uma atividade, porem n estou entendendo muito bem o código,
gostaria de saber como faço pra verificar se um numero já está na lista, como é um assunto novo estou meio perdido, como eu deveria ao menos fazer a função de busca funcionar ? o código que tenho até o momento.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

struct duplo{
    int num;
    struct duplo* ant;
    struct duplo* prox;
};

typedef struct duplo Duplo;

Duplo* criaListaNula(){
    return NULL;
}
Duplo* criaNo(){
    Duplo *novo = (Duplo*) malloc(sizeof(Duplo));
    return novo;
}

Duplo* insereInicio(Duplo* Cabeca, int dado){
    Duplo* novo = criaNo();
    novo->num = dado;
    novo->ant = NULL;
    if(Cabeca == NULL)
{
        Cabeca = novo;
        novo->prox = NULL;
        novo->ant = NULL;
    }else{
        novo->prox = Cabeca;
        Cabeca = novo;
    }
    return novo;
}
void imprime(Duplo* Cabeca)
{
    Duplo* aux = Cabeca;
    while(aux != NULL)
    {
        printf("%d ", aux->num);
        aux = aux->prox;
    }
}
int buscaDado(Duplo* Cabeca, int dado)
{
    Duplo *aux;
    for(aux = Cabeca; aux != NULL; aux = aux->prox)
        if((aux->num = dado))
        {
            return 1;
        }
    return 0;
}

int main()
{
    Duplo *Cabeca;
    int resp;

    Cabeca = criaListaNula();
    Cabeca = insereInicio(Cabeca, 5);
    Cabeca = insereInicio(Cabeca, 4);
    Cabeca = insereInicio(Cabeca, 7);
    Cabeca = removeInicio(Cabeca);

    resp = buscaDado(Cabeca, 4);
    if((resp=1))
    {
        printf("encontrado");
    }
    else
    {
        printf("nao encontrado");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Você tá fazendo atribuição onde deveria estar fazendo comparação (tá usando = onde deveria usar ==) nas seguintes linhas:

```
 if((aux->num = dado))
```

e

```
 if((resp=1))
```

Nesse último if não precisa nem comparar com 1, qualquer valor diferente de 0 é avaliado como positivo, podendo ficar apenas:

```
 if(resp)
```

Já que você ta atribuindo o valor retornado da função à variável cabeça na main, a sua função de inserir no início pode ser simplificada:

```
 Duplo* insereInicio(Duplo* Cabeca, int dado){
     Duplo* novo = criaNo();
     novo->num = dado;
     novo->ant = NULL;
     novo->prox = Cabeca; 
     return novo;
 }
```

Comment: Deu certo mano, mt obrigado, vc sabe me dizer como eu faria para criar duas listas ? ou se esse código ja cria 2, pois é duplamente encadeada, eu não consegui distinguir ou entender como se cria 2 listas nesse código

Comment: é só declarar outro ponteiro pra essa outra lista: Duplo *Cabeca, *Cabeca2;